# Function to pause the console does not work

Tags: c

I have a small function which should pause the console, but actually does nothing

```c
void getch()
{
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}
```

Also, I don't want to use `system("pause")` or `scanf("%c", &temp)`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*. Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: @MikeCAT do you have a reference for that being UB?

Comment: `getchar()` alone should be enough, creating a separate function is unnecessary. My guess is that you have other inputs before, and your `getchar()` caches some character that is left in `stdin`.

Comment: `fflush()` is to flush a write buffer, and `stdin` is read-only. If this isn't pausing properly you probably have unread data on `stdin`, so you'll need to read it first.

Comment: It's relevant to say that MSVC actually defines the behavior of `fflush` with input stream.

Comment: @HerrNilsen, if my guess is correct here is a link where you can find a methods to clear stdin: [How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7898215/6865932)

Comment: @AKX C18: 7.21.5.2  2 If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: @anastaciu MSVC defines and says it is a no-op :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, yes, pesky MSVC, why do they do those things? I feel like it's just to agravate people ;).

Comment: @anastaciu it changed at some point, the universal CRT says that it is no-op and the older MSVC docs say it discards input buffer. ROTFL.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, what a mess. There a nice answer by Jonathan Leffler around here that goes into some detail. Out of curiosity I tested it and in my case it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AKX [c - Using fflush(stdin) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)